# Print key of list w/o knowing its position

Tags: list, loops, lua, lua-table

I have a list that contains many keys:

```
mylist = {"a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "3", ...}
```

and I want to print the key for example that has value "x", without knowing it's exact position in the list. That mean I have to run the whole list and till "x" is found and print it. How could I do this? Seems easy question but it confuses me a bit... Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, *run the whole list and till "x" is found and print it*, do you have any trouble doing that?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for key, value in pairs(mylist) do
  if value == "x" then print(key) end
```

You can also create another mapping, eg.

```
mapping_list = {}
for key, value im pairs(mylist) do
  mapping_list[value] = key
```

(assuming that list elements are unique) then, you'd be able to

```
print(mapping_list["x"])
```